# Database Specific Migration Code

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, migration, rails-migrations

I'm creating an application that needs to run under multiple databases. I currently have some code in a migration that I only want run under specific databases (postgresql and mysql). Any way of setting this up? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your migration has access to a database connection in [`connection`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html#method-c-connection) and the connection has an [`adapter_name`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/AbstractAdapter.html#method-i-adapter_name) method so you can just ask it what sort of connection it is:

```
def self.up
    case connection.adapter_name
    when 'PostgreSQL'
        # Do PostgreSQL stuff
    when 'MySQL'
        # Do MySQL stuff
    else
        # Blow up and catch on fire. Or silently ignore it depending on your needs.
    end
end
```

I'm not sure if I have the MySQL adapter name right but the technique is sound and you can easily check the MySQL adapter name yourself.