# Rails: specifying production environment specific migrations

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, heroku

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Database Specific Migration Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178303/database-specific-migration-code)

So I run MySQL locally since it's what I have installed and it makes sense to me.

But Heroku uses Postgre and it doesn't have the same field types.

I.e. I use longblob locally and it becomes bytea in my production environment.
I use tinytext locally which becomes just text

How do I specify different environments inside of my migrations so I don't have to edit my migrations just for pushing to heroku? (I would like to keep them syntactically correct for my local machine)

Any other suggestions?

Comment: if you are deploying your app to heroku (and therefor using postgres) - use postgres locally as well - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/how-do-i-use-sqlite3-for-development

Comment: @house9 is right, don't do this to yourself. There are a lot more differences between MySQL and PostgreSQL than a couple of data types. Database portability is largely a myth unless you're prepared to write your own portability layer (no, ActiveRecord isn't that layer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand wanting to run what you're used to locally, as it's easier. Plus, IMO, setting up Postgres locally has always been a pain in the past. However, it really is important to run your development on the same DB as your production server. If you're a Mac user there's a good solution now, brought to you by none other than the Heroku postgres team:

[http://postgresapp.com/](http://postgresapp.com)

Use that and you don't have to worry about this. Otherwise, follow the [answer posted by Mu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178303/database-specific-migration-code), which will let you do the evil two database thing :)

Comment: thanks for that! I will just use that solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing here but why don't you create two different migration files, one for development and another for production and use something like this:

```
rake db:migrate VERSION=00000000000001 RAILS_ENV=production

rake db:migrate VERSION=00000000000002 RAILS_ENV=development
```

Comment: I guess that could work, I figure there's so much magic in rails already I was hoping for a cleaner method.

Comment: maybe there is... thats why I say that I'm just guessing, have you tryed something like the gemfile does? using group :development do (...) just another guessing trying to help :)